# getting data in python from web page with multiple tables

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse below webpage to get name of stocks hitting now all time high or low in the exchange.

https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/HighLow.html?Flag=H#

however, when i download the webpage using beautiful soup and check the data only half stocks show up, this is because
 the page has 2 pages in it so 25 stocks on 1 page and 25 on another using above method i am able to parse first page only ,
 the url is also same if i click on second page, please help how can i solve this ?

Comment: You don't "download webpage" with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

The site has an api endpoint that returns the data to you in a nice json format. You can get that json formatted response, then normalize it to create a table. Now when it does this, it returns 2 tables, so I'm not sure if you want that second one. If not, I stored each of them separately, and then appended them to have them together.

```
import requests    
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/MktHighLowData/w?Grpcode=&HLflag=H&indexcode=&scripcode='

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'Grpcode':'', 
'HLflag': 'H',
'indexcode':'' ,
'scripcode':'' }

jsonObj = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

df_table = json_normalize(jsonObj['Table'])
df_table1 = json_normalize(jsonObj['Table1'])

df = df_table.append(df_table1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
     ALLTimeHigh         ...                         dt_tm
0        1019.95         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
1         263.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
2          24.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
3          35.90         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
4          29.75         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
5          43.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
6         140.40         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
7          15.39         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
8         724.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
9        1495.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
10        123.15         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
11        121.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
12        238.50         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
13         89.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
14        819.95         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
15        112.40         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
16         49.95         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
17        330.85         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
18        167.45         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
19         25.10         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
20        940.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
21        165.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
22           NaN         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
23        239.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
24        151.55         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
25         34.35         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
26        256.15         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
27         49.75         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
28        103.25         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
29         50.50         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
..           ...         ...                           ...
87        135.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
88        219.80         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
89         58.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
90        494.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
91        285.30         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
92         55.65         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
93          4.45         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
94         50.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
95         50.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
96         92.50         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
97        154.80         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
98         82.40         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
99        293.85         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
100       396.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
101        98.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
102       144.60         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
103        11.50         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
104        42.95         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
105       313.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
106      1120.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
107        87.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
108        82.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
109       214.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
110       505.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
111      1525.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
112       220.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
113        36.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
114       170.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
115       549.50         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03
116      4990.00         ...           2019-02-25T16:00:03

[168 rows x 19 columns]
```